# scala annotation argument needs to be constant but final val does not make it

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, annotations

In this snippet,

```
@SwaggerDefinition(...authorizationUrl = 
SecurityConstants.authorizationUrl)
```

and given that

```
final object SecurityConstants {
  final val authorizationUrl: String =..
}
```

(only one of the two finals should be ok, but still)
I was expecting/hoping that this would compile with 2.12.3 but it is however giving 
"annotation argument needs to be a constant; found: SecurityConstants.authorizationUrl
[error]         authorizationUrl = SecurityConstants.authorizationUrl,"

Also calling Java static method System.getenv("a") in annotation brings the same error, that is

```
@SwaggerDefinition(...authorizationUrl = System.getenv("a"))
```

Please help,
Nicu M

Comment: http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiKeyAuthDefinition.html has no `authorizationUrl` and other parts also seems to have different keys. Are you sure you are using the proper key in the code?

Comment: @GáborBakos, I believe what is referenced here is related to [OAuth2](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/oauth2/) i.e. a part of [OAuth2Definition](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/current/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/OAuth2Definition.html

Answer (score 24):

`final val` references can be used as Java annotation arguments under two conditions:

1. The value assigned to the `final val` must be a literal.
2. You must **not** specify the type of your `final val` explicitly.

So, this will work:

```
final val AuthorizationUrl = "http://something.com"
```

but these will **not** work:

```
final val AuthorizationUrl = "http://something.com".trim
final val AuthorizationUrl: String = "http://something.com"
```

The condition no. 2 may seem especially weird but it's required for the compiler to internally retain the information that the `final val` is holding not just a `String` but some particular literal string value (the compiler must infer a [literal type](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#literal-types)).

Answer (score 4):

It is really important what is behind `..` in the

```
final val authorizationUrl: String =..
```

In Scala and Java annotation arguments must be ***compile-time*** constants rather than just "final". So `System.getenv("a")` (or any other function call) directly or via intermediate `val` will not do it as this is not a compile-time constant. This is done that way because annotations are designed to be introspectable at the compile time i.e. if you just have a `.class` file, you must be able to get the value of all the fields of the annotation. So the  compiler must know all the values at the compile time.

**Update**

Actually Swagger itself relies on the compile-time introspection. So what exactly did you expect it to do with your `System.getenv` call? What specification Swagger should have generated for such annotation? And why do you need it at all? AFAIU if you have several environments, you should put URLs of the production (i.e. the one accessed by outside users) into the definition.